TypeError: (intermediate value) is not iterable Sequelize findOrCreate
I am facing some issues using findOrCreate together with sequelize. I tried to apply the code bellow in order to catch sequelize errors and make sure the user transaction works.
const { User } = require('../models/user');
const { ValidationError, Sequelize } = require('sequelize');
const { getSequelizeErrorObject } = require('../utils/functions');

const registerController = async (req, res) => {
  const queryCondition = {
    where: Sequelize.or(
      { username: req.body.username },
      { email: req.body.email },
    ),
    defaults: {
      username: req.body.username,
      email: req.body.email,
      password: req.body.password,
    },
  };

  const [user, userCreated] = await User.findOrCreate(queryCondition).catch(
    (err) => {
      if (err instanceof ValidationError) {
        const sequelizeError = getSequelizeErrorObject(err);
        return res.status(400).send(sequelizeError);
      }

      return res.status(500).send({
        message: 'Something went wrong when trying to process the request',
      });
    },
  );

  if (userCreated) {
    const { username, email, id } = user;
    return res.status(200).json({ username, email, id });
  }

  return res.status(400).send({
    message:
      'The email/username are already associated within the app, try to sign in instead',
  });
};

module.exports = registerController;

I am getting this error:


TypeError: (intermediate value) is not iterable
    at registerController (C:\Users\filip\Desktop\Projects\elfmetter\server\controllers\registerController.js:18:31)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

It just happens if I send this kind of data (that hits the sequelize validation):
"email": "",
"password": "m",
"username": ""

Tried to also use the promise chain (.then, .catch) but would like to avoid that if possible.
also tried to add a try catch block around the whole thing, but the error was the following:
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent to the client
Any help with this? (The docs are not very clear on how to handle things with sequelize)
Updated:
Also Tried to do a normal async await with try catch around like bellow:
const { User } = require('../models/user');
const { ValidationError, Sequelize } = require('sequelize');
const { getSequelizeErrorObject } = require('../utils/functions');

const registerController = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const queryCondition = {
      where: Sequelize.or(
        { username: req.body.username },
        { email: req.body.email },
      ),
      defaults: {
        username: req.body.username,
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password,
      },
    };

    const [user, userCreated] = await User.findOrCreate(queryCondition);

    if (userCreated) {
      const { username, email, id } = user;
      return res.status(200).json({ username, email, id });
    }

    return res.status(400).send({
      message:
        'The email/username are already associated within the app, try to sign in instead',
    });
  } catch (err) {
    (err) => {
      if (err instanceof ValidationError) {
        const sequelizeError = getSequelizeErrorObject(err);
        return res.status(400).send(sequelizeError);
      }

      return res.status(500).send({
        message: 'Something went wrong when trying to process the request',
      });
    };
  }
};

But now I get an infinite spinner if I do the call like before, seems like it is trying to execute the query for way to long without any result. It should catch the validation errors because my User model has all of the 3 fields as required.
Thanks a lot, appreciated!

I think the problem is that your await call for .findOrCreate() is actually waiting on the Promise instance returned by the call to .catch(). If instead you placed the await inside a try block, you could catch the exception in an ordinary catch.

Just updated my answer, I tried it, similar result. It is like I need the catch at the instance to catch sequelize validation errors, otherwise they wont get cought at the final catch :/

Yea well that's not how try / catch works. If there's an exception thrown in that try block, control will transfer immediately to the catch. And you need to take the catch code out of that => function; the block of the => function should be the block that comprises the catch.

Ah, copy paste issue, it worked fine now, thanks a lot :). Noobie issue :D
